# What is the limit of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N (\frac{i}{N})^l\frac{1}{N}$?

Tags: calculus

I would like to know the limit of the above summation as $N$ tends to infinity. Thank you guys for hints or solutions. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the definition of Riemann integral for
$$
\int_{0}^{1}x^kdx
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!